# finding the largest binary number from a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, binary, max

I have a data of some binary numbers in few range of cells, from A2 to A8, B2 to B8, and so on, till G column. 
Now, I want to check the largest binary number from the above Rows and paste it to the cell, two row below the last used range. (i.e., Largest binary number from Row A to be paste in A10, and so on).
I am not finding any function which can find the value of binary numbers, and the code which I ran finds out the max number considering those as natural numbers.
Your help will be appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: How long are the binary data(bit wise)? And are all the binary the same length?

Comment: The length is of 5 bits, and yes all are of same length. [00110, 10110, 10000], etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay first i made a function that converts binary to decimal and stored in a module. (You can store it wherever you want) This function handles any size binary

```
Function BinToDecConverter(BinaryString As String) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Len(BinaryString) - 1
        BinToDecConverter = CDec(BinToDecConverter) + Val(Mid(BinaryString, Len(BinaryString) - i, 1)) * 2 ^ i
    Next
End Function
```

Afterwards i made the sub that loops through all binarys on sheet1 (Might need to change this for your sheet)

```
Sub FindLargestBinary()
On Error Resume Next
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim tempVal, tempRow As Integer
Dim iCoulmn, iRow As Integer

For iCoulmn = 1 To 7 'Run from A to G
    tempRow = 2
    tempVal = 0
    For iRow = 2 To 8 'Run from row 2 to 8
        If BinToDecConverter(ws.Cells(iRow, iCoulmn).Value) > tempVal Then tempVal = BinToDecConverter(ws.Cells(iRow, iCoulmn).Value): tempRow = iRow ' Check if current binary i higher then any previous

    Next iRow
    ws.Cells(iRow + 1, iCoulmn).Value = ws.Cells(tempRow, iCoulmn).Value 'Print highest binary
Next iCoulmn

End Sub
```

Hope this helps you out..

Comment: This works very well! Just for the curiosity, if I had the data in Excel, and put the VLOOKUP formula: =VLOOKUP(MAX(C8:C13),C8:D13,2,FALSE), will it solve my problem without using VBA.??

Comment: To be hones I do not know, give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excel function Bin2Dec to change them into decimal

```
Function MaxBin(r as range)
Dim curmax as long
Dim s as range
For each s in r
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.Bin2Dec(s.Text) > curmax Then curmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Bin2Dec(s.Text)
Next s
MaxBin = curmax
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your binary values are text strings this formula converts the values to numbers, finds the `MAX` and then converts back to a text string

`=TEXT(MAX(A2:A8+0),"00000")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

or you can use this version which finds the max using `AGGREGATE` function and doesn't require "array entry"

`=DEC2BIN(AGGREGATE(14,6,BIN2DEC(A2:A8+0),1))`

Comment: @jayyM Which formula are you using? There can’t be anything in the range other than the binary values. If VLOOKUP works, as per your comment then I assume your values are numeric, in which case I expect you could use just MAX(A2:A8)

Comment: Yes, there's nothing except the binary numbers. VLOOKUP is fine. But I assume excel treats binary numbers as normal values only, and there won't be any need to convert it to Decimal first. Using MAX is simpler i think, than VLOOKUP